# Italics display issue

Tags: fonts

My italics are displaying weirdly in a number of programs, including Firefox, Chrome and KDiff3. I have also been having another [graphical issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84451/screenshot-captures-no-windows). I am using 11.10 with the Gnome 3.2.1 shell and ttf-mscore-fonts 3.3ubuntu4. Does anyone know what the issue is?

My system settings are:

> Driver: VESA: RV710
>
> Experience: Standard
>
> Video card: ATI Technologies Inc RV710 [Radeon HD 430]

[image: Graphical issues]

Comment: Your problems seem to be with your video driver. What video card do you have and why are you using the vesa driver ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Updated with details

Comment: The real fix is to switch to the radeon driver. Is there a reason why you are forcing vesa?

Comment: @scottl: I wasn't forcing it, just trying to find something to work

Comment: @scottl: How can I make it use Radeon?

Comment: Radeon is the default driver. Does it exhibit the issue?

Comment: have you installed Compiz(ccsm) ??? and did you activate wobbly-windows feature ???

Comment: @Naruto: I installed Compiz, but I didn't enable that feature

Answer (score 2):

You should try installing the catalyst driver, your card is listed as supported.

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

That second command should configure X , if you receive an error message, post it here.

Otherwise reboot.

Additional reference

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

Comment: Any update on your progress ?

Comment: Didn't work. I tried a few other things and actually stuffed my system up worse. I'm thinking the solution is reinstall. I've awarded you the bounty because your last link is a very good resource

Comment: Sorry it did not work out for you. Best of luck.